# Using Mockito to stub and execute methods for testing

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I've asked a couple of jUnit and Mockito oriented questions recently and I'm still really struggling to get the hang of it. The tutorials are all for very simple examples, so I'm struggling to scale up my test cases to work for my classes.

I'm currently trying to write some test cases for a method I have in one of my agents in a webapp. The method interacts with a couple of other methods inside the agent to validate some objects. I just want to test this one method right now.

Here's what I have tried to do:

1. Create a Mockito object of my agent like so:

   `MyProcessingAgent mockMyAgent = Mockito.mock(MyProcessingAgent.class);`
2. Setup stubs(hopefully the right term) using Mockito.when like so:

   `Mockito.when(mockMyAgent.otherMethod(Mockito.any(arg1)).thenReturn(requiredReturnArg);`
3. Try executing my method like so:

   `List myReturnValue = mockMyAgent.methodThatNeedsTestCase();`

I was expecting to things in `myReturnValue`, but received 0 instead so I tried to debug. When I call the method, it never executes. I have a debug point at the first line in the method that never gets touched.

If I want to execute the code in one method of a class, but force other methods in the class (one's that try to interact with databases in the outside world) to return faked out values. Is this possible with Mockito?

It appears that my current method of approach is not a correct testing style, but I'm not sure how to move forward. Can I mock my class and have one method be executed like normal while other methods are stubbed to return my given values so that I don't have to deal with data access during testing this one method?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You are confusing a `Mock` with a `Spy`.

In a mock **all methods** are stubbed and return "smart return types". This means that calling any method on a mocked class will *do nothing* unless you specify behaviour.

In a spy the original functionality of the class is still there but you can validate method invocations in a spy and also override method behaviour.

What you want is

```
MyProcessingAgent mockMyAgent = Mockito.spy(MyProcessingAgent.class);
```

A quick example:

```
static class TestClass {

    public String getThing() {
        return "Thing";
    }

    public String getOtherThing() {
        return getThing();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final TestClass testClass = Mockito.spy(new TestClass());
    Mockito.when(testClass.getThing()).thenReturn("Some Other thing");
    System.out.println(testClass.getOtherThing());
}
```

Output is:

```
Some Other thing
```

NB: You should really try to mock the dependencies for the class being tested **not** the class itself.

Comment: Please see my statement regarding spies and let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @JohnB I think you are correct. I have expanded by answer. I did not realise the OP was calling the method internally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed descriptions, it is very helpful. So, what both answers are recommending (to clarify) is that I'm attacking the wrong class with Mock. Instead I should be mocking all the data access objects that my class needs, then use a normal instance of my class for testing?

Comment: So, I was wrong. At least on my box, a spy will catch internal calls. I set up a scenario where m1() calls m2(). I spy the object and stub m2(). In my test I call m1(). m2() in the object is never reached, the stub in invoked. IMHO this is still bad practice but good to know.

Comment: @JohnB yeah, seems we jumped the gun a little. `spy` works fine. Obviously not the way to do it _really_ but some bad unit tests are probably better than none at all...

Comment: In a spy, the original implementation doesn't necessarily have to be there.

Answer (score 7):

So, the idea of mocking the class under test is anathima to testing practice. You should NOT do this. Because you have done so, your test is entering Mockito's mocking classes not your class under test.

Spying will also not work because this only provides a wrapper / proxy around the spied class. Once execution is inside the class it will not go through the proxy and therefore not hit the spy. UPDATE: although I believe this to be true of Spring proxies it appears to not be true of Mockito spies. I set up a scenario where method `m1()` calls `m2()`. I spy the object and stub `m2()` to `doNothing`. When I invoke `m1()` in my test, `m2()` of the class is not reached. Mockito invokes the stub. So using a spy to accomplish what is being asked is possible. However, I would reiterate that I would consider it bad practice (IMHO).

You should mock all the classes on which the class under test depends. This will allow you to control the behavior of the methods invoked by the method under test in that you control the class that those methods invoke.

If your class creates instances of other classes, consider using factories.

Comment: +1 for the use of a word like anathema, seems harsh, but I think I get your point. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the testing, I guess I just came at this from the completely wrong angle.

Comment: probably true of a A-word. The fact that you are even doing unit testing is a good sign. Keep it up. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You've nearly got it. The problem is that the [Class Under Test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClassUnderTest) (**CUT**) is not built for unit testing - it has not *really* been [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)'d.

Think of it like this…

- I need to test a function of a class - let's call it *myFunction*
- That function makes a call to a function on another class/service/database
- That function also calls another method on the **CUT**

In the unit test

- Should create a concrete **CUT** or `@Spy` on it
- You can `@Mock` all of the other class/service/database (i.e. external dependencies)
- You *could* stub the other function called in the **CUT** but it is not really how *unit* testing should be done

In order to avoid executing code that you are not strictly testing, you could abstract that code away into something that can be `@Mock`ed.

In this *very* simple example, a function that creates an object will be difficult to test

```
public void doSomethingCool(String foo) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject(foo);

    // can't do much with obj in a unit test unless it is returned
}
```

But a function that uses a service to get MyObject is easy to test, as we have abstracted the difficult/impossible to test code into something that makes this method testable.

```
public void doSomethingCool(String foo) {
    MyObject obj = MyObjectService.getMeAnObject(foo);
}
```

as MyObjectService can be mocked and also verified that .getMeAnObject() is called with the *foo* variable.

Comment: if _myFunction_ and _myFunction2_ are part of the **CUT**, and _myFunction_ calls _myFunction2_ as stated in your example, wouldn't Spy based partial mocking be the only option? should _myFunction2_ be moved out of the **CUT** and "injected" even though it is an integral part of the **CUT** responsibility? what am i missing?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. Spy based partial mock is the best option, although you _could_ just test both methods together. My example was more about the problem when methods in the *CUT* create objects that you might want to verify behaviour on or assert values in, and that could be accomplished by refactoring the *CUT* to use a factory or external service to create those objects which _can_ be mocked and injected.

Answer (score 1):

SHORT ANSWER

How to do in your case:

```
int argument = 5; // example with int but could be another type
Mockito.when(mockMyAgent.otherMethod(Mockito.anyInt()).thenReturn(requiredReturnArg(argument));
```

LONG ANSWER

Actually what you want to do is possible, at least in Java 8. Maybe you didn't get this answer by other people because I am using Java 8 that allows that and this question is before release of Java 8 (that allows to pass functions, not only values to other functions).

Let's simulate a call to a DataBase query. This query returns all the rows of HotelTable that have FreeRoms = X and StarNumber = Y.
What I expect during testing, is that this query will give back a List of different hotel: every returned hotel has the same value X and Y, while the other values and I will decide them according to my needs. The following example is simple but of course you can make it more complex.

So I create a function that will give back different results but all of them have FreeRoms = X and StarNumber = Y.

```
static List<Hotel> simulateQueryOnHotels(int availableRoomNumber, int starNumber) {
    ArrayList<Hotel> HotelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    HotelArrayList.add(new Hotel(availableRoomNumber, starNumber, Rome, 1, 1));
    HotelArrayList.add(new Hotel(availableRoomNumber, starNumber, Krakow, 7, 15));
    HotelArrayList.add(new Hotel(availableRoomNumber, starNumber, Madrid, 1, 1));
    HotelArrayList.add(new Hotel(availableRoomNumber, starNumber, Athens, 4, 1));

    return HotelArrayList;
}
```

Maybe Spy is better (please try), but I did this on a mocked class. Here how I do (notice the anyInt() values):

```
//somewhere at the beginning of your file with tests...
@Mock
private DatabaseManager mockedDatabaseManager;

//in the same file, somewhere in a test...
int availableRoomNumber = 3;
int starNumber = 4;
// in this way, the mocked queryOnHotels will return a different result according to the passed parameters
when(mockedDatabaseManager.queryOnHotels(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(simulateQueryOnHotels(availableRoomNumber, starNumber));
```