# Why is this Mockito.mock object being called instead of being mocked?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm unit testing my class and encountered this situation: I mock an object using Mockito and call a method on that object. When I do that, I expect the real method not to be called, and program flow to continue. What is happening is that the real method is being called and I got a NullPointerException, because that is what would happen if I called the method with this parameter.

Shouldn't the Mockito.mock prevent this behavior?

The [Mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2) says `By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976157/2272160) confirms my expected behavior of `In a mock all methods are stubbed and return "smart return types". This means that calling any method on a mocked class will do nothing unless you specify behaviour.`

The code:

```java
public class BrokenTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldPassBecauseItIsMocked() throws IOException {
        Object anyObject = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = Mockito.mock(ObjectOutputStream.class);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(anyObject);
    }
}
```

I expected this test to pass, but i get a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1108)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at packageName.BrokenTest.shouldPassBecauseItIsMocked(BrokenTest.java:14)
    ...
```

(`BrokenTest.java:14` is the `objectOutputStream.writeObject(anyObject);` line actually)

P.S.: I am not really trying to test `ObjectOutputStream` but a class of mine that uses `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object object)`. The problem really arose when I did `myObjectWithMockedObjectOutputStream.methodThatCallsWriteObject()`

Comment: writeObject is final. Mockito (until the recent versions, and if you configure it specifically to do so) can't mock final methods.

Comment: Are you actually mocking Object.class, or another specific type? Also, do you know what version of Mockito/JUnit you're using?

Comment: @JBNizet I think that is it. Will check and comment here. It usually shows a warning when I do something similar, like Mockito.mock(String.class) but maybe that is because I am using and old version of Mockito (1.10.19).

Comment: @JJBrown Yes, actually mocking Object.class. And using 1.10.19 (that's probably a problem, as I commented to JB Nizet..)

Comment: Yes, @JBNizet was the solution. If you'd like to write an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBNizet answered correctly on the questions comments.

> writeObject is final. Mockito (until the recent versions, and if you configure it specifically to do so) can't mock final methods.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito does not chenge the way the language works. The Methods are called in the order they apper in the code. 
This mean in the case of a mocked method like this:

```
when(mockObject.getSomething()).thenReturn(SOMETHING_ELSE);
```

that first `getSomething()` is called on the mocked object and then the infrastructure of mockito replaces the return value before giving control to your code under test.

This implies that if `getSomething()` calls some dependencies of the mocked object the latter are not initialized and result into a NPE.

The work around for this is to use the other form of configuring a mock:

```
doReturn(SOMETHING_ELSE).when(mockObject ) .getSomething();
```

<sup>please not that the closing brace of `when` moved from behind the method to before the `.`.</sup>

This allows Mokito to intercept the complete method call so that no NPE is thrown.