# Error mocking @Inject classes JUnit Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm having some troubles using JUnit with Mockito. First of all I give you all the info that I have.

JWTValidator.java

```
@Inject
JWTUtils jwtUtils;

public void validateJWT(String jwt) { //The main function returns true, false or an exception
[...]
Claims claims = jwtUtils.getClaims(jwt); //claims = null here!
[...]
}
```

JWTUtils.java

```
public void getClaims(jwt) { //This should return an Exception with the JWT that I use on the JWTTestServlet.java
[...]
}
```

JWTTestServlet.java

```
@InjectMocks
private JWTValidator jwtValidator;
        
@Mock
private JWTUtils jwtUtils;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test(expected=Exception.class)
public void testJWTWithoutGUID() {
final String jwt = ""; //Some JWT 
    String message = "";
    try {
        jwtValidator.validateJWT(jwt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    assertTrue(message.contains(MSG_WITHOUT_GUID));
}
```

The point is when I call the *getClaims* function of JWTUtils, it doesn't work, I receive a null field.
I've tried with many different annotations but it doesn't work either. JWTUtils is null or the function returns a null.

I can debug JWTValidator but I can't debug JWTUtils.

Can you please help me?

Thank you so much
Best regards

Comment: "JWTUtils is null or the function returns a null" - which one is it?

Comment: Can you post your entire class rather than a portion

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
The solution was that I have to define the behaviour of the mocked class (JWTUtils)

```
when(jwtUtils.getJWTClaims(jwt)).thenReturn(new DefaultClaims());
```

Now when I call this function I don't have a null object.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

By default, all methods of a mock return “uninitialized” or “empty” values, e.g., zeros for numeric types (both primitive and boxed), false for booleans, and nulls for most other types.

I think what you need is not a Mock but a Spy: [Using Mockito to stub and execute methods for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976008/using-mockito-to-stub-and-execute-methods-for-testing)